# Is there any way to simplify my java code?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner here. I'm trying to determine if the user has given 3 sides of a triangle, the program will check what type of triangle it is. Is there any way that I can shorten this code without the use of advanced codes?

Here's my code.

```
double a = 13
double b = 8
double c = 7
double leg1, leg2, leg3;
        if(a > b && a > c){
            leg1 = Math.pow(a,2);
            leg2 = Math.pow(b,2);
            leg3 = Math.pow(c,2);
                if(leg1 == leg2 + leg3) {
                    System.out.println("Right.");
                }else if (leg1 > leg2 + leg3){
                    System.out.println("Obtuse.");
                }else if (leg1 < leg2 + leg3){
                    System.out.println("Acute.");
                }
        }else if(b > a && b > c){
            leg1 = Math.pow(b,2);
            leg2 = Math.pow(a,2);
            leg3 = Math.pow(c,2);
            if(leg1 == leg2 + leg3) {
                System.out.println("Right.");
            }else if (leg1 > leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Obtuse.");
            }else if (leg1 < leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Acute.");
            }
        }else if (c > a && c > b){
            leg1 = Math.pow(c,2);
            leg2 = Math.pow(a,2);
            leg3 = Math.pow(b,2);
            if(leg1 == leg2 + leg3) {
                System.out.println("Right.");
            }else if (leg1 > leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Obtuse.");
            }else if (leg1 < leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Acute.");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid triangle.");
        }
```

Comment: You may want to try asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: First sort your input sides such that always `a` is the longest and `c` is the shortest side. This saves some comparisons later.

Comment: You would also need to explain _in detail_ what you consider "advanced".

Comment: Try putting the printing at the very end, based on some boolean(s) that are set in your `if` statements

Comment: Please refer https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask for questions to not ask. Just to guide you right - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this it's a bit offtopic, but nevermind this time.

Essentially you are writing this snippets 3 times, so it has to be encapsulated in a function

```
if(leg1 == leg2 + leg3) {
                System.out.println("Right.");
            }else if (leg1 > leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Obtuse.");
            }else if (leg1 < leg2 + leg3){
                System.out.println("Acute.");
            }
```

can be something like

```
public void defineTriangle(double leg1, double leg2, double leg3){
    if(leg1 == leg2 + leg3) {
                    System.out.println("Right.");
                }else if (leg1 > leg2 + leg3){
                    System.out.println("Obtuse.");
                }else if (leg1 < leg2 + leg3){
                    System.out.println("Acute.");
                }
}
```

so your code can call 3 times this function (or, better, invoke 3 times this method).

Then, you are basically generting 3 numbers as input, sorting them from upper to lower, than invoke the method to define the triangle.

Basically you need an array...

```
double a = 13;
double b = 8;
double c = 7;
double[] sides = {a,b,c};
Arrays.sort(sides);
defineTriangle(sides[0], sides[1], sides[2]);
```

However, this approach it's not really Java-like, since it uses primitives and not objects.